# Adobe Flash Professional CS5 tutorials

Tags: adobe, flash-cs5

I trying to learn how to program in Adobe Flash Professional CS5.
 However i never used anything from Adobe before.
 Can anyone advice me if any sources are available for me to find out how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lynda.com has some really good DVDs.

http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=59964
http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=69088
http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=67685
http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=68387

Answer (score 2):

Here is the nice [start](http://www.vtc.com/products/Adobe-Flash-CS5-Tutorials.htm)

Comment: Karin du vet väl att man inte kan posta såna dära saker :P alltså olagliga nedladdningar hehe :P